# Kindle Fire Not Recognized when plugged into PC

Tags: rooting, usb, amazon-kindle-fire

I have just got a Kindle Fire and I want to root it and Install Android Market on it. I am having a problem that is ticking me off big time. I plug my Kindle Fire to my computer (Windows 7 Professional) and I get the message in the Fire screen that states that I can now start to transfer files to my device but two things are happening:

1. Every time I plug the USB end to any USB port on my computer my Internet goes down !!! WTF!!!!
2. When double clicking on my computer the Kindle Fire does not seem to be recognized correctly as it shows under Devices with Removable Storage. When clicking on that drive mapping I get a pop up saying: "Insert disk"

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I have installed the Kindle drivers by adding **0x1949** to the **adb_usb.ini** and now under **Device Manager** I do not longer see "Kindle" under Others. Now I see **Android Phone/ Android Composite ADB Interface**

I double click on My Computer and I still do not see the Kindle anywhere. I have the letter I: which appears there once I plug the Kindle Fire but its not clickable. What am I doing wrong?

I have followed this instructions to the dot correctly. http://www.jayceooi.com/2011/12/13/how-to-install-kindle-fire-adb-usb-driver/ but yet I cannot see the Fire as an icon in my computer

Comment: Those instructions allow you to access the Fire over `adb`, which is different than using it as a mass storage device. It sounds like you're having an issue with the latter, but does `adb` interaction work? If you can issue `adb devices` and see the device serial listed then it's working (the instructions discuss this at the end).

Comment: That's true you are right with your comment. I can interact with adb but I could not access it. I went to Best Buy and exchanged the Micro USB cable for another one and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions I have followed in the link above do the job. The solution to my two problems listed above was:

Replace this Micro/Mini USB to USB adapter

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Rocketfish%26%23153%3B+-+1.5%27+USB+Cable/1000247.p?id=1218207305639&skuId=1000247&st=RF-CC1MC&cp=1&lp=1

...with this one:

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Rocketfish%26%23153%3B+Mobile+-+Micro+USB+Data+Transfer+Cable/2077196.p?id=1218308698225&skuId=2077196&st=rocketfish%20micro%20usb%20&cp=1&lp=3

It sounds weird but trust me do not get Micro USB to USB adapter from the first link. You will not be able to access the Kindle Fire as a storage device, guaranteed.